# How to split slugs in Svelte router in all possible options?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to build URL patter, like this `[lang]/category/[name]-[suffix]`, where:

- `suffix` is one of a few strings, for example: `['super-product', 'great-gadget', 'ta-ta-ta']`
- `name` is a multiple word slug, like `a-bb-ccc`

To implement it, I decided to use [Matching](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#advanced-routing-matching):

```
export function match(param) {
  let result = /^(super-product|great-gadget|ta-ta-ta)/.test(param); 
  return a;
}
```

For the URL `/en/category/a-bb-ccc-super-product/`, `param` is `bb-ccc-super-product`.
Q: How to make Svelte splits URL into slugs in all possible options, like: `a` + `bb-ccc-super-product`, `a-bb` + `ccc-super-product`, ..., `a-bb-ccc-super` + `product`, and not just in one `a` + `bb-ccc-super-product`?

Also, I tried to use [handlers](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle) to resolve this issue, failed as I was not able to change URL.

- "@sveltejs/kit": "1.0.0-next.310"
- "svelte": "3.47.0"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. Svelte will match like a non-greedy regular expression matcher, so in your case of `[name]-[suffix]`, `name` will always hold whatever comes *before* the first matching hyphen (`-`) and `suffix` will hold whatever trails that first matching hyphen.

For reference, quoting the SvelteKit documentation (relevant bit bolded):

> A route can have multiple dynamic parameters, for example src/routes/[category]/[item].svelte or even src/routes/[category]-[item].svelte. **(Parameters are 'non-greedy'; in an ambiguous case like x-y-z, category would be x and item would be y-z.)**

The easier solution would be for you to pick a different param separator like underscore (`_`), or a double-hyphen (`--`), or whatever sequence of characters you are positive will not appear *within* your params.

Alternatively, if you absolutely want, or need, to stick with your current naming scheme, it would be easier to treat it as a single param (`name`) and then parse this *single* param yourself using your own regular expression (as you have attempted, but mistakenly kept using 2 params).